# Can't access folder on external drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, permissions, external-hard-drive

I'm in a pickle. Yesterday, I was looking for a couple of old photos I had taken years ago. (I'm an armature photographer and over the years I've accumulated many terabytes of RAW images, edits and PS files.) In order to get to the images I was looking for, I was switching between two disks on my external USB dock. Found the files on the second drive, extracted them and then put the original disk back. This is a hot-swappable dock with an eject button for the disk so I didn't worry about ejecting the drives from Windows first.

This morning, when I turned my system back I couldn't access the external drive. When I tried it said something like "parameter is incorrect." So after reading some stuff on the Internet, I decided to run CHKDSK. I made the mistake of running it with /r switch. So after a couple of hours of running, and with the counter still showing 30+ hours to completion--it’s a 8TB drive--I decided to abort CHKDSK by closing the Command Prompt window. I was on Stage 4 of CHKDSK when I aborted, so I think I was fairly safe. Rebooted and successfully ran CHKDSK with the /f switch.

Now when I double-clicked on the drive I got the message

> D: is not accessible. Access is denied.

I gathered from more reading that I needed to change permissions to the drive. I right-clicked on the disk, went into the "Security" tab and from there added my username and gave it full permission. I could finally get back into the drive.

But the strange thing was that I could only see two folders, one the WD Utilities folder and one folder with a small collection of miscellaneous photos. The folder with essentially the entire library was invisible. So I executed the TAKEOWN command, which ran successfully. During the process I could see it scroll through all files and folders, so I know  that data is there, just invisible to me.

Sorry for the long post but it all comes down to this simple question: How do I make the main folder/subfolders visible again?

Comment: Ownership allows the owner a privilege to change security even if security says you can't That is all ownership does, it doesn't give you any other access. So after taking ownership you have to give yourself permissions to access the files with `icacls`.

Comment: I tried running icacls. This is what I got...

C:\WINDOWS\system32>ICACLS d:\ /reset /T
d:\: This operation is not allowed as it would create an un-usable ACL.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files

Comment: `reset` doesn't do what you think. `icacls F:\ /grant Administrator:F /t`.

Comment: So replace "F:\" with my drive letter designation, i.e. "D:\" (without the quotes, of course)?

Comment: Yes, with or without quotes.

Comment: I ran the command "icacls d:\ /grant Administrator:F /t". It simply added "Administrator" to the list of Group/User names to the drive and the two folders that I already had access to. It did not bring back my primary folder/subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that the primary photos folder was somehow changed to a protected operating system folder. I was able to see it by unchecking the "Hide protected operating system files" option in file manager. How this happened I have no idea. Many of the subfolder names have also changed to "dirxxxx.chk", where the "xxxx" are numerical sequences like 0001, 0002, etc., but the individual contents within seem to be intact. I'm going to move all the contents to a separate drive, and do a thorough diagnostics on this one to make sure it's not failing, and reformat it. Thank you all for your interest and help!